# How to effectively revise a forgotten subject while doing research?

Tags: phd, research-process, physics

I am currently in the fourth year of my Ph.D. and I am fully engrossed in my research work. Sometimes I find it hard to revise some forgotten concept from a related subject. What is the best strategy to revise old concepts while one is simultaneously doing one's research work?

For example in Physics, sometimes a term comes in the research work that I have somewhat forgotten but not completely erased from my memory. Do I need to do a thorough study of an old concept or just revise it in accordance with its use in the research work?

Comment: "revise" or "revive". That is "change" or "remember"?

Comment: @Buffy I believe that "revise" means in India what "review" means in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If revising those forgotten concepts is beneficial to your work, this is the time that you can grasp those concepts well. It depends on the level you need the concept. Sometimes your research modifies some of the concepts or adds to them. In this case, you will need to do a thorough study, making sure that you are on the right track. But, sometimes, a quick reminder is enough to know the basic meaning of a technical term so you can continue reading through a research paper.

Seldom can one skip through a few technical concepts without knowing them well and yet understand related ideas or concepts.

Answer (score 2):

If you think you're likely to need to revise several topics that are situated in the same undergraduate course, you might consider TAing on that course: teaching material can be a very effective way to learn it, perhaps more thoroughly than you did the first time round.